# Python if statement condition using dictionary string

Tags: python

I would like to use dictionary value of the key to verify if condition is true e.g

```
dictionary = [{'Class': '>50K'},{'Class': '<=50K'}]
    for i in dictionary:

        if i['Class'] == '<=50k':
            po_list_count +=1

        else:
            rich_list_count +=1

    print(po_list_count,'---',rich_list_count)
```

print should be 1 --- 1 instead I get 0 --- 2
I have tried with `if i['Class'] in ['<=50k']`  but same result.
Is it something I do not understand about how if statement works or perhaps how it treats strings?

Comment: Your capitalizations don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for a capital "K":

```
if i['Class'] == '<=50K':
```

You used one in `dictionary`:

```
dictionary = [{'Class': '>50K'},{'Class': '<=50K'}]
#                                        here--^
```

Answer (score 0):

in your definition, you use upper case `<=50K` and in your if statement you use lower case `k`

Answer (score 0):

Because `k` and `K` is not the same character. You'll have to match it:

```
if i['class'] = '50K':
```

Or, a better trick: Just check both in lowercase!

```
if i['class'].lower() = '50k':
```

Hope this helps!